PowerShell Core Function App on Linux: Logs Missing When Local Authentication is Disabled in Application Insights
I am using a PowerShell core 7.4 function app running on Linux. And I have application insights where local authentication is disabled. I have deployed the Powershell script which monitors the license expiry dates and needs to send data to application insights. The function app identity is enabled and it has a metric publisher role in application insights. The problem with the application when local authentication is disabled is, that it will not display any logs when test/run or logs.
When I disabled the local authentication on application insights, the script worked like a charm. I don't know what the issue was, but I am expecting it to be an authentication issue with identity.
Below is the code that I am using
param($Timer)

$InstrumentationKey = $env:APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTAION_KEY

# Application Insights Endpoint (ingestion endpoint for custom metrics)
$ApplicationInsightsURL = "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track"

$minimumDaysValid = 20

#Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
#function LoginAzureAutomation {
 #   try {
 #       $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
 #       $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
#        $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName AadGraph).token
#        Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $token -AccountId $AzureContext.Account -TenantId $AzureContext.Tenant
#    }
#    catch {
#        Write-Error -Message "Unable to connect to Azure!" -ErrorAction Stop
#        throw $_.Exception
#    }

#}

#LoginAzureAutomation

# Get the path to the JSON file
$jsonFilePath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "licensesdates.json"

# Log the timer status if available
if ($Timer -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Function triggered by Timer: $($Timer.ScheduleStatus.Last)"
}

# Load the licenses from the JSON file
$licenseData = Get-Content -Raw -Path $jsonFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($license in $licenseData.licenses) {
    $licenseName = $license.licenseName
    $expirationDate = $license.expirationDate

    $expirationRealDate = Get-Date $expirationDate
    $today = Get-Date ("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f (Get-Date))
    $daysDifference = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $expirationRealDate).Days

    # Determine the status message and exit code
    $msg = switch ($daysDifference) {
        { $_ -gt $minimumDaysValid } {
            "OK: $licenseName license has $daysDifference days left."
        }
        { $_ -gt 0 } {
            "WARNING: Take action! $licenseName license expires in $daysDifference days."
        }
        { $_ -eq 0 } {
            "ALERT: $licenseName license expires TODAY!"
        }
        { $_ -lt 0 } {
            "EXPIRED: $licenseName license expired $((-1 * $daysDifference)) days ago."
        }
        default {
            "UNKNOWN: Could not determine status for $licenseName."
        }
    }

    # Prepare the payload for Application Insights
    $OperationId = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    $Payload = @{
        iKey = $InstrumentationKey
        name = "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Metric"
        time = (Get-Date).ToString("o")
        data = @{
            baseType = "MetricData"
            baseData = @{
                ver = 2
                metrics = @(
                    @{
                        name = "LicenseDaysRemaining"
                        value = $daysDifference
                    }
                )
                properties = @{
                    "LicenseName" = $licenseName
                    "StatusMessage" = $msg
                    "OperationId" = $OperationId
                    "DaysRemaining" = $daysDifference
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Convert the payload to JSON
    $PayloadJson = $Payload | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10

    # Send the data to Application Insights
    Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri $ApplicationInsightsURL `
        -Method 'Post' `
        -Body $PayloadJson `
        -ContentType "application/json"

    Write-Host $msg
}

Below is the host.json file
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 5
      },
      "enableDependencyTracking": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host": "Error"
    }
  }
}

Below is the profile.ps1
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Write-Output "MSI secret found. Authenticating with Managed Identity."
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process 
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
}
else {
    Write-Output "MSI secret not available. Skipping authentication."
}

Below are the requirements.psd1
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
    # 'Az' = '12.*'
    'Az' = '12.*'
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.2.3'
    'AzureAD' = '2.0.2.182'
}

And below is licensesdates.json
{
    "licenses": [
      {
        "licenseName": "Apple Distribution",
        "expirationDate": "2024-11-01"
      }
    ]
    }

I have tried many ways of authentication in the script and commented on the code on the profile. PS1 and vice versa. I have also tried to remove the authentication loop in the profile. PS1, but I have had no luck.
And we have the same configuration in .net and it's working fine. Does anyone know about this issue?

As per documentation, you need a new setting/env variable for out-of-the-box logs to be sent to app insights (i.e.: Write-Host, Write-Error....):
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_AUTHENTICATION_STRING:

The value contains either Authorization=AAD for a system-assigned managed identity or ClientId=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>;Authorization=AAD for a user-assigned managed identity.
...
The APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING setting is still required.

For custom request, you will need to get an access token (see Microsoft Entra authentication for Application Insights):
$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://monitor.azure.com"
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $($token.Token)";
}

Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Headers $headers
...



APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING is already their in environmental variables and the instrumentation key is consumed in script. And now added Authorization=AAD in variables but still same issue

you need APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_AUTHENTICATION_STRING to be Authorization=AAD. is it what you setup?

Still I getting the 401 error. I am using the same script. so i need to do any changes?
Response   : StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:errorDetails: { "itemsReceived": 1,"itemsAccepted": 0, "appId": null, "errors": [{  "index": 0, statusCode": 401,"message": "Authentication required" } ]}
Response   : StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: POST, Reque…tent-Length: 445

If I remove the ikey (instrumentation key), I am getting "message": "Invalid instrumentation key"

ho, tha's the Invoke-RestMethod that fails ?

yes and Invoke-webrequest also.I have mentioned the script what I am using and associated files also mentioned their. Can you please take a look on that.
I have even tried with HTTP client but same issue
$content = New-Object System.Net.Http.StringContent($payload, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/json")
$response = $httpClient.PostAsync($applicationInsightsURL, $content).Result

you need to get a token to call app insights and add it to the http heard, will post an update later today

I forgot to mention I have tried pass token in headers and I am getting below error
"message": "Authorization not supported". So I have updated the application endpoint URL to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2.1/track as v2 is not supported, after update I am getting "message": "Authentication required",although I am passing the token which is valid

You should be sending the log to the ingestion endpoint as defined in the app insights connectionstring

Same issue are updating the endpoint url also
